# matlab vectorization and avoid for loop

Tags: matlab, vectorization

There are two matrix X and M and I need to obtain the following matrix D

```
m = 20; n = 10;
X = rand(m,n);
M = rand(m,m);
M = (M + M')/2;

D = zeros(n,n);
for i = 1:n
    for j = 1:n
        D(i,j) = X(:,i)'*M*X(:,j);
    end
end
```

When n and m are large, the computation of D is very slow. Is there any way to speed up?

Comment: Just do `X.'*M*X`?

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be:

```
D = 0.5*X.'*(M+M')*X
```

(This is a slight modification of the solution provided by Divakar, so that the correct matrix D is returned)